# How to take user input from a text box and display using a list C#?

Tags: c#

```
  private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     List<String> names = new List<String>();
     names.Add(textBox1.Text);
     names.Add(textBox2.Text);
     names.Add(textBox3.Text);




     displayTextBox.Text = displayMembers(names);
     displayTextBox.Text = string.Join(" ", names);
  }

  public string displayMembers(List<String> names)
  {
     foreach (String s in names)
     {
        return s.ToString();
     }
     return null;
  }
```

This is what i have so far, but what i need to do is be able to clear the textbox and type in something new and it will display in displayText box as well as what was entered the first time... I am new to programming and cannot figure out how to keep adding to the displaybox. Thanks

Comment: You want to clear the textbox and then put the old data back in (that you just erased) next to whatever you are typing?  That seems odd.  Why not just leave the data there if you are just gonna turn around and put it back again?  Can you clarify why?

Comment: displayMembers will allways return after the first string in names

Comment: I need to be able to type in name add it to the displaybox, clear textboxes, and add additional names to the displaybox. if that makes sense

Comment: @Logan No, it doesn't. At least not how you are telling it.

Comment: `s.ToString()`?  Why are you calling `ToString()` an an object that is *already* a string?  In any event, it will only show the first name in the `List<T>` because you told it to - note that you have `return s.ToString()` in the `foreach` loop - you'll return the first time through the loop and there will be no more loops.

Comment: For example, i need to type in a first name, middle name, last name and add the whole name on one line, then clear the text boxes and add another name to the list...

Comment: my answer will do what you want.

Comment: @Logan - Start with a working example you find on the internet.  An example that is close to what you want to do.  Then make little modifications to it until you get to where you want to go.  ListBox is a good place to start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this?  I am guessing you want to `append` whatever is typed in to the `displayTextBox` control.

BTW, your `displayMembers()` won't work like you want, it returns the very first element in the enumeration.

The code below will append all the entered names to the DisplayTextBox:

```
displayTextBox.Text = displayTextBox.Text +
 " " + textBox1.Text + " " +textBox2.Text +" "+ 
textBox3.Text +" "+textBox4.Text;
```

Alternatively you should store a list of names like this:

declare an instance List variable:

```
private List<string> _names = new List<string>();
```

Then instead of changing the text of the `displayTextBox` simply add the name to the list:

```
_names.Add(textBox1.Text + " " +textBox2.Text +" "+ 
textBox3.Text +" "+textBox4.Text);
```

Then use the list to drive what is displayed in `displayTextBox`:

```
displayTextBox.Text = string.Join(" ", _names);
```

So to wrap it all together, change this:

```
//instance var
private List<string> _names = new List<string>();

private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
_names.Add(textBox1.Text + " " +textBox2.Text +" "+ textBox3.Text +" "+textBox4.Text);

 displayTextBox.Text = string.Join(" ", _names);

 textBox1.Text = "";
 textBox2.Text = "";
 textBox3.Text = "";
 textBox4.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: yes that is what i am talking about, but now that i have all the names in the displayTextBox using add button in win forms, i want the user to be able to clear textboxes and add more names to the list that is already there. does that make sense

Comment: You could simply clear all the text boxes after you've appended but the problem is you are just creating a big long string.  you need to generate a true list of strings, i will post an example.